# $watch is not detecting changes to length of an array when called from inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, I'm creating a threaded discussion forum. I'd like to add a badge to notify when a thread contains new comments. Here's my code, which is applied to posts which contain comments. It is inside a directive, which also contains a compile, if that may be causing the problem?:

```
if($scope.post.child_posts){
    var scope = $scope;
    scope.$watch(function(){
        return scope.post.child_posts.length;
    }, 
    function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue, oldValue);
    }, true);
};
```

This is working to output the number of replies for each level of the thread; however, the newValue and oldValue are always the same! When I refresh the page, it updates the numbers, but they are still the same. I've done some searching, and it looks like there was a bug where the newValue and oldValue were the same, but it appears to have been fixed, and I'm using the latest version.

I'm pretty new to programming, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: where is above code located, in link or compile? it should be in link because compile called once only on start. BTW this is a diference between link and compile

Comment: It's located inside of a controller named "PostController" which is defined in the directive.

Comment: @user3776805 where is the rest of the code? this works for me: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P8QZ8y1et5sAIRnzpjJY?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, Mosho. I tried your code, but I'm still having the same problem. My post.child_posts is updated each time a new reply is submitted, so I can't set it to an empty array. If I do, then it doesn't display the replies. Is there a way to just check for changes to this array length, without having to redefine it?

Answer (score 0):

please change above code to this:

```
    $scope.post.child_posts = [];

    $scope.$watch('post.child_posts.length', 
        function(newValue, oldValue){
            if(newValue !== oldValue)
               console.log(newValue, oldValue);
            else
               console.log(newValue);
        }
    );
```

what i am guessing is that : the if condition might be preventing a $watch setup, also you dont need deep watch (third parameter true), given that you are watching length and not the array...

Comment: Thanks, Harish. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem. My post.child_posts is updated each time a new reply is submitted, so I can't set it to an empty array. If I do, then it doesn't display the replies. Is there a way to just check for changes to this array length, without having to redefine post.child_posts?

Comment: No, I tried that as well. I think the problem is that I need a counter to last through the page refresh, because when I refresh the page, or submit a new reply, which refreshes the page, it also resets the $watch. I think that's why it's always showing the same.